# SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character in flask

Tags: forms, flask, non-ascii-characters

I have a simple form with select field. The issue is that the value uses Cyrillic alphabet. like bellow:

```
class Add_menu_form(Form):
    title = TextField('Title', [validators.Length(min=1, max=250), validators.Required()])
    menu_type = SelectField('Menu type', 
                choices=[('simple', 'обычный'),
                        ('blog', 'блог'),
                        ('products', 'продукция')])
```

when I run the app it gives me an error:

```
SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xd0' in file /home/app/admin/forms.py 
on line 26, but no encoding declared; 
see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

Can you please tell me the simplest way to overcome it? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should add the encoding your file is using on top of the script in order to use *special characters* literals in your source:

```
# coding: utf-8
```

For example. It also should be good to use `unicode` strings: `u'обычный'` for example.

You can read this for further references: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/